# Hexo how to make content replace on generate?

Tags: hexo

I need to replace text strings on site when generate.

Created a file myGenerateWork.js and executed with node myGenerateWork.js but doesn't work.

This is myGenerateWork.js

```
var Hexo = require('hexo');

var hexo = new Hexo(process.cwd(), {});

hexo.init().then(function () {

    hexo.extend.filter.register('after_post_render', function(data){
      data.content = data.content.replace(/@(\d+)/, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">#$1</a>');
      return data;
    });

    hexo.call('generate', {}).then(function(){
        return hexo.exit();
    }).catch(function(err){
        return hexo.exit(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

If "hexo server" is running and you execute "generate", the "after_post_render" filter is executed and the content replace correctly works but the data.content with new data is ignored by hexo.

Solution: before doing a generate execute a "hexo clean".